# Difference between kCFStreamSSLLevel and kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel

Tags: networking, nsstream, cfnetwork

Can someone please explain difference between these 2 properties? They accept same set of values defined in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cfstream/cfstream_socket_security_level_constants

`kCFStreamSSLLevel` is set in `kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings` dictionary and `kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel` directly.

Documentation doesn't say much about any of them.

Answer (score 0):

Looking [at the source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-128.2/Stream/CFSocketStream.c.auto.html), setting the property `kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel` internally just creates a dictionary where the property value is stored for the key `kCFStreamSSLLevel` and the created dictionary is passed to a function that is also called when the property `kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings` is set.

So this code:

```
CFReadStreamSetProperty(
    stream, 
    kCFStreamPropertySocketSecurityLevel,  
    kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL);
```

is equivalent to this code

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef settings =   
    CFDictionaryCreateMutable(
        NULL, 0,
        &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks,
        &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);

CFDictionaryAddValue(
    settings, 
    kCFStreamSSLLevel,
    kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL);

CFReadStreamSetProperty(
    stream, 
    kCFStreamPropertySSLSettings,  
    settings);
```